# ZIP drive (parallel) on FreeBSD 12

Tags: usb, freebsd, hardware

Is there a way to spin Iomega zips (parallel to usb) on Freebsd 12 natively? Using virtualization for basic file transfer is overkill and theres not much about zip drives after FreeBSD5.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iomega zip drives are still natively supported at least on the [FreeBSD 12.1 hardware list](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/12.1R/hardware.html).

You do however need to compile your own kernel as described in [Chapter 8. Configuring the FreeBSD Kernel](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig.html) and add the [vpo -- parallel to  SCSI interface driver](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?vpo(4)).

The notes about a SCSI disk as root etc. from this [FreeBSD 6.1 article about zip drives](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/6.1-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/en/articles/zip-drive/article.html) will still be relevant. The zip drive will act as a SCSI drive and then might be probed before the internal SCSI disk.

So the good part is that it is at least still available.

Now comes the pain. The vpo driver is using the [ppbus -- Parallel Port Bus system](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ppbus(4)). To my knowledge there is [no USB implementation for ppbus](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-hackers/2016-December/050364.html).

My guess is that when you plug in your USB➜parallel adapter it will register as a `ulpt` which is a raw character device. If it to my surprise registers a `lpt` then you might be in luck (check with [dmesg](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?dmesg(8))).